# Getting a specific layer as file in ArcGis JS 4.x

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

The idea is simple:

1. User draws graphic layer (similar visual example to my own https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=sketch-geometries)
2. Saves the layer in a file (similar example, only from ArcGis JS 3.x https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/extractdata-amd.html)
3. So later could add the said layer to the map and see it, maybe even edit it again (Not needed right now for this ticket).

So basically I am a bit stuck at step 2. Is there a way to extract and save a specific layer as a file in ArcGis JS 4.x?

Comment: The saving to shapefile part (step 2) needs to be a service hosted on arcgis server or arcgis server online. Do you have access to such service? If not you will have to use an external javascript library that convert geojson to shapefile on client-side.

Comment: Thank you. That got me a little bit further, since I searched and found such library (https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write), which I will most likely test in Monday.

Comment: That's the library I was going to suggest you to try. But personnaly I never tryed it.

Comment: After reading a bit more about shp-write library, you might have problems to use it on client-side because it was made for Node.js (server side). You can try to use browserify.js but it's going to be complicated to handle all dependancies